# Need help deciphering the path on a Windows shortcut's target for printing PDF files direct to Canon print driver

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, printer, command-line-arguments

I have a Canon printer (imagePROGRAF TM-305) that has direct print software that creates a link on the desktop that allows me to drag and drop a PDF file on top of the link icon and it goes direct to the printer.  It works great.  However, I have another laptop where I tried to replicate the same setup but I am getting different (undesirable) results in the printed PDF such as printing wide empty borders when it should be borderless.

Here is the target under the link properties for the link that functions correctly.  I am unable to decipher the info beyond the filepath to help me troubleshoot.  I can't find info on /st and /ss and the info between the braces.

"C:\Program Files\Canon\imagePROGRAF Direct Print & Share\ipfdpu.exe" /st /ss:{C23DED62-5784-4C14-BA47-AEBF5C084868}

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: The link to the executable contains invalid characters. You sure that’s the path?

Comment: The "info between the brackets" looks like a GUID a common identifier in Windows. You may find this GUID when searching the Windows registry for this string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses Ramhound and Robert.

Ramhound:  Yes, the link to the executable is a cut/paste from the properties of the link I mentioned.

Robert:  I searched the registry for the GUID and came up empty.  Lot's of entries for Direct Print and Share however, but nothing that seemed relevant to my situation or that I could decode/understand.

Again, thanks for the help.  If you have any additional suggestions I'd love to hear them but I do appreciate the time spent so far on my inquiry.

Comment: Please dont use the answer section for comments. Instead you can edit the question

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was wondering about that.